# Document Management System - Architectural Design Question

Tags: c#

I need to design an in-house server-based system that will store hundreds of thousands of files (images, spreadsheets, text documents) with users accessing metadata as well as files remotely. What are my options? ASP.Net MVC or WinForms with WCF service?  I am really stuck here because I am a newbie.

Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first advice would be: **Don't.**

Plenty of people have implemented very complex and feature complete Content Management Systems, so don't reinvent the wheel.  Additionally many of them have lots of extensibility points so you should be able to customize it to the needs of your organization.

Take a look at [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/), its open source and should provide what you need

Comment: Agreed.  Someone already create them, why bother making another one.  I would go with buy + customize instead of build in this case.  SharePoint comes to mind.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you need [SharePoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_SharePoint_Services) ( also [SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/default.aspx) ).

SharePoint ( WSS ) edition is free and very extensible using .Net.

The new Sharepoint Foundation 2010 replaces WSS 3.0 for Windows Server 2008.  It can be downloaded from the Microsoft link above.

Comment: SharePoint 2010 has just been released so the WSS equivalent is now SharePoint Foundation 2010 http://sharepoint.microsoft.com

Comment: Thanks, updated.  Foundation 2010 seems to require Server 2008 though.